# Making changes to Conda environment permanent instead of falling back to the default

Tags: environment, conda

I can set my environment to make it `house_rank`, and it shows on my terminal:

```
house_rank sgilmour14-Ubuntu
```

But after a reboot, it goes back to my standard terminal, and removes `house_rank`.

Is there a way to make it permanent, so I don't have to re-add my environment every time I reboot?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04

```
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  /home/sgilmour14/anaconda3
house_rank               /home/sgilmour14/anaconda3/envs/house_rank
```

```
sgilmour14@sgilmour14-Ubuntu:~/house_rank_backend$
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Bash shell, just activate the environment in your `.bashrc`, by editing it and adding the following at the end of the file:

```
conda activate house_rank
```

You can do that more easily by running this command:

```bsh
echo "conda activate house_rank" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then close and reopen your terminal or run the following command for the change to take effect:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```